# a week vs in a week time

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> He draw masks on 2300 images **a week**.
>
> He draw masks on 2300 images **in a week time**.

Is it grammatical and idiomatic to use both **a week** and **in a week time**?

Comment: _In a week time_ is not idiomatic. As The Photon says, _in a week's time_ has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

"He draws 2300 images a week" implies this is an ongoing activity that has happened every week.

Something happening "in a week's time" typically refers to a single future event which we expect to happen about a week from now.
For example,

> I will be visiting New York in a week's time